# Compiled executable stops on MIPS router with "not found"

Tags: gcc, compilation, mips, cross-compiling

I need some GPIOs on my ASUS RT-AC66U. That's why I made a circuit board with an MCP2221A.

With [this source](https://github.com/zkemble/libmcp2221) I was able to build the executable file and run it on my x86-64bit machine (Xubuntu 16.04) and everything works fine.

Now I have cross-compiled the same source to MIPS and get this error:

```
frashman@ASUS-RT-AC66U:/tmp/home/root/gpio$ ls -la
drwxrwxrwx    2 frashman root           180 Nov  1 12:16 .
drwx------    4 frashman root           100 Nov  1 12:16 ..
-rw-rw-rw-    1 frashman root           485 Nov  1 12:16 Makefile
-rwxrwxr-x    1 frashman root         10044 Nov  1 12:16 gpio
-rw-rw-r--    1 frashman root         19857 Nov  1 12:16 hid.c
-rw-rw-r--    1 frashman root         13870 Nov  1 12:16 hidapi.h
-rw-rw-r--    1 frashman root         24758 Nov  1 12:16 libmcp2221.h
-rw-rw-r--    1 frashman root          3122 Nov  1 12:16 main.c
-rw-rw-r--    1 frashman root          4456 Nov  1 12:16 main.o
frashman@ASUS-RT-AC66U:/tmp/home/root/gpio$ ./gpio 
-sh: ./gpio: not found
```

Ok, so I build the source on the router itself with a [Debian subsystem](https://www.hqt.ro/how-to-install-debian-wheezy-mipsel/) and the binary file runs without error (except for the 0 found devices - it was not connected at the time when a wrote this)

```
root@ASUS-RT-AC66U:/home/admin/gpio$ ./gpio 
Starting!
Looking for devices... found 0 devices
Opening device... No MCP2221s found
```

But, if i want to run this binary on the main system of the router it will stop with the same error:

```
frashman@ASUS-RT-AC66U:/tmp/mnt/entware/entware/debian/home/admin/gpio$ ./gpio 
-sh: ./gpio: not found
```

This is the makefile:

```
PROJECT=gpio

SOURCES= \
    main.c

CFLAGS= \
    -c \
    -Wall \
    -Wextra \
    -Wstrict-prototypes \
    -Wunused-result \
    -O3 \
    -std=c99 \
    -fmessage-length=0 \
    -mtune=mips32r2 \
    -mips32r2

LDFLAGS= \
    -s

LDLIBS= \
    -lmcp2221

EXECUTABLE=$(PROJECT)

CC=mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.c=.o)


all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) $(LDLIBS) -o $@

.c.o:
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $@

clean:
    rm -rf *.o $(EXECUTABLE)

.PHONY: clean all
```

Does anyone have an idea why that could be?

Answer (score 0):

run `readelf -l gpio | grep -i interpreter`.  it should show a path to the ldso that needs to exist.  you can compare it to running readelf on `/bin/sh` on the system to see what it expects.

if the paths are different, you can add `-Wl,-dynamic-linker,/path` to your Makefile's LDFLAGS (replace `/path` obviously with the real path).